# How to set the default tab in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a question regarding my Angular Bootstrap UI.

I have something like:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller='sCtrl'>
    <tabset id='tabs'>
        <tab heading="Title1" >
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Title2" active ="true">
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Title3">
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

My problem is everytime I add `active='true'` in my tab, I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.fn (http://test.com/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js:2762:11)
    at h.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:106:71)
    at h.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:108:370)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:71:120)
    at C (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:75:241)
    at XMLHttpRequest.y.onreadystatechange (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:76:280)
```

I've searched google and moved jQuery file loaded before Bootstrap file but still getting the same error. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it me or you used active="true' instead of active="true" ??

Comment: @Zerquix18 that was a typo. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @drew_w what is myTabs[1]? Is myTabs an id?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is exactly what you reference in your question - if you set `active` to true either in code or in the HTML, it selects the tab. There are two ways to create tabs:

- **Static Tabs:**

  ```
  <tabset id="tabs">
    <tab heading="Title1"></tab>
    <tab heading="Title2" active="true"></tab>
    <tab heading="Title3"></tab>
  </tabset>
  ```

  Here if you set `active="true"` the tab will be the default active tab.
- **Dynamic Tabs:**

  *HTML*

  ```
  <tabset id="tabs2">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active"></tab>
  </tabset>
  ```

  *Javascript*

  ```
    $scope.tabs = [
      {"title": "Dynamic 1", "active": false},
      {"title": "Dynamic 2", "active": true},
      {"title": "Dynamic 3", "active": false}];
  ```

To see both of these working, check out this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nR9GNIhGAmha8Rh85lUa?p=preview

Comment: yes but there will be undefined is not a function error in the console. same in your plunker +1 though

Comment: @FlyingCat If you comment out the first "inline" version and use the dynamic version only that doesn't have the `undefined is not a function` error. I'm guessing that the html is loading before the angular boostrap has finished loading which is why the first option has the issue. Hope that at least helps some.

Answer (score 0):

The tab's `active` property must point to a variable and not a constant. You're telling the second tab to always be active.

`active` also can't be an expression. It seems they are working on changing how `active` works. Check out [this github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/611) for more.